# Machine get hang after upgrade from 17.04 version to 18.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, 17.04

I have install Ubuntu 17.04 version from usb drive on my Windows 10 64 bit machine. After installation everything was perfect.

I got the notification for system upgrades to 18.04 version. After upgrade system hangs every time when I start. Not even a single application or terminal can be run. It's too much frustrating.

I have also try to re-install latest Ubuntu version on same machine through bootable USB drive, but even that process also get struck at some point and machine get crash and getting following error massage:

```
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or solution for this?